# How to do ORM using reverse engineering in Hibernate in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, orm, intellij-idea, reverse-engineering

I have 100 tables and most of them have average 40-50 fields.
Some table have 5-6 fields, so I can make it's object relational mapping easily with DB.

But I have so many numbers of tables as well as fields so Is it possible to create ORM using reverse engineering in Intellij IDEA ?

If yes then how to do so ?

I have done mapping simple like :

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "pat_id_seq")
@Table(name = "pat")
public class Patron extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "p_id")
    private String pID;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String userPassword;
}
```

I am using PostgreSQL as a DB provider.

So any help on it to so fast ?

Help..

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have figured it out by now...but for anyone else trying to resolve this. 
If you have added plugin support and it is enabled (check boxed) do the following as well.

Right click on your project "Add Framework Support..." --> Scoll down to JAVA EE Persistence. At that point you will see the Persistence option in "View --> Tool Windows --> Persistence".

Answer (score 1):

If you use IntelliJ Community Edition you can install JPA Buddy plugin. It enables reverse engineering: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=az9ghvGczys.

Answer (score 0):

open the persistence tool window, then click generate persistence mapping.

View > Tool Windows > Persistence

Comment: I can't find `Persistence` in the list. I have there message, project, run, TODO, structure, bean validation, commander, etc.

Comment: @user3145373ツ you might need to enabel the plgin then - and you are using the full version, and not community?

Comment: I am using ultimate version. and how to enable the plugin sir ?

Comment: File > settings > plugins

Comment: In that `Persistence Framework Support` is enabled means bundled / Installed. or Shall I have to install another one ?

Comment: There is a box to tick to install. Bundled just means its part of intellij and not an external plugin. Yes use it.

Comment: *As of IntelliJ 2016.2, you need to add the JPA facade to the module in order for the Persistence entry to appear in the Tool Windows list

Comment: ..but what if I use Community Edition? then I can't do the Reverse Engineering?