# How to create the xxx.hbm.xml file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: xml, hibernate, intellij-idea

I want to create a `Admin.hbm.xml` in my project use IntelliJ IDEA.

like the below tutorial, I create the `xx.hbm.xml`, the DOCTYPE and hibernate-mapping is exists in the `xx.hbm.xml`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But in IntelliJ IDEA:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

There is no xml file option when I create a file.

If I choose the `XML Configuration File` -> `JSP Tag Library Descriptor`, it will create a file with suffix (`.tld`).

So, how can I create `xxx.hbm.xml` configuration file easily?

Answer (score 1):

Give,

```
New > File > and save it as file-name.xml
```

Also, I would suggest you to use the reverse engineering provided by intelliJ

Comment: what mean of `reverse engineering`, friend?

Comment: @244boy sure, Its a process where we can create database entity classes from the database schema, see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293958/how-to-do-orm-using-reverse-engineering-in-hibernate-in-intellij-idea